# PLPGSQL Stored Procedure exits LOOP on exception

Tags: loops, exception, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

Trying to implement a LOOP inside PLPGSQL Stored Procedure which should handle an exception scenario and move to the next cycle of the LOOP, but the Stored Procedure terminates on occurrence of exception.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE poc_exception_normalise(INOUT processed BOOLEAN)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM poc_exception_temp_staging_table petst
        LOOP
            BEGIN
                CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_poc_person
                (
                    id   INT8  NOT NULL,
                    data SUPER NOT NULL
                );
                INSERT INTO temporary_poc_person VALUES (rec.id, rec.data);
                RAISE INFO '--> record = %', rec.id;
                INSERT INTO poc_person (SELECT tpp.id                            AS id,
                                               tpp.data."firstName"::VARCHAR(15) AS first_name,
                                               tpp.data."lastName"::VARCHAR(15)  AS last_name
                                        FROM temporary_poc_person tpp);
                DROP TABLE temporary_poc_person;
                DELETE FROM poc_exception_temp_staging_table WHERE id = rec.id;
                RAISE INFO '--> DELETED RECORD = %', rec.id;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    RAISE NOTICE 'Exception occurred while normalising %', rec.id;
                    DELETE FROM poc_exception_temp_staging_table WHERE id = rec.id;
                    RAISE INFO '--> DELETED RECORD = %', rec.id;
                    processed = FALSE;
            END;
        END LOOP;
    RAISE INFO '--> processing complete !!';
    processed = TRUE;
END;
$$;
```

Is it impossible to continue in LOOP after exception is encountered?

Comment: why not simply avoid the exception? .... Exceptions are not control flow ....

Comment: The loop will be continued after the exception has been handled. Note that there are a few exceptions which are *not* caught by `WHEN OTHERS`.

Comment: I can see the flow printing the log for faulty record which means it is going into the condition WHEN OTEHRS THEN

logs:

--> record = 1
--> DELETED RECORD = 1
--> record = 2
Exception occurred while normalising 2
--> DELETED RECORD = 2

-> I had 3 records in the table so the loop should have continued to 3rd row but it did not